# Java program just stops when I try to execute a terminal command

Tags: java, intellij-idea, methods

I'm trying to write my first program in java. It's purpose is to root and unroot my Nexus 6P which I can do all in terminal with adb and fastboot, but I want to make a program that I can run and have menus of sorts. I found a way to execute commands weather it be batch, or bash (I use both Windows and Linux). My main class is

```
class main{

public static void main(String[] args){

    String version = "0.0.1";
    String commandIn = "adb";
    int OSType = OSValidator.sys();


    ExecuteShellCommand.main(commandIn);



    System.out.println("Welcome to Nexus Tools: " + version);
    System.out.println("This program will help you Root and UnRoot your Google Nexus 6P");
```

It does not make it past the `ExecuteShellCommand` it just stops.

Here is the `ExecuteShellCommand` class I found online and slightly changed

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExecuteShellCommand {

public static void main(String inputCommand) {

    ExecuteShellCommand obj = new ExecuteShellCommand();

    String command = inputCommand;

    String output = obj.executeCommand(command);

    System.out.println(output);

}

private String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}

}
```

the program just stops and I dont know whats going wrong.

Comment: `p.waitFor();` ... you should be reading the `InputStream` of the process before this, otherwise the process may stall

Comment: when I run your program I got an exception saying `Cannot run program "adb": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`. so, I've changed `adb` with `ipconfig` and it worked just fine. Check that `adb` command is properly resolved.